# Side-effect of std::srand/rand and libuuid uuid_generate

Tags: c++, random, uuid

For testing I need reproducible random numbers. The randomness isn't that important.
Currently I'm setting a seed `std::srand(x)` and use `std::rand()` to generate. As expected the numbers are always the same on multiple runs with the same seed.

For some other parts I need UUIDs. I use the utils-linux libuuuid.

But running this code:

```
  std::srand(2);

  uuid_t uuid;
  
  int x = std::rand();
  uuid_generate(uuid);
  int y = std::rand();
```

`y` is different on every run.

I already tried to use `uuid_generate_time`,`uuid_generate_time_safe` but this doesn't generate fully random UUIDs on multiple calls:

```
d4e25820-92ca-11eb-9b39-f91e898522ad
d4e25821-92ca-11eb-9b39-f91e898522ad
d4e25822-92ca-11eb-9b39-f91e898522ad
d4e25823-92ca-11eb-9b39-f91e898522ad
```

Is there any other way I could implement this?

Comment: Do you want the same UUID:s - or why do you care about what `rand()` returns? Do you want a PRNG that is totally unaffected by `uuid_generate`? If so, use one of the generators in `<random>`, like `std::mt19937`.

Comment: Yes, the rand() result should be unaffected (or at least all the same after the uuid_generate call). For testing it would also be nice to have same UUIDs but this isn't important.
I though that rand() does use its own pseudo-random-generator after seeding and uuid_generate (in my current setup) /dev/urandom.
I'll try out the generators.

Comment: If high-quality randomness from `/dev/urandom` is available, your seed won't matter. In that case, `uuid_generate` will pick random numbers from an entropy pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As expected the numbers are always the same on multiple runs with the same seed.

Until they are not. `rand()` is not required to use a certain algorithm. It can change if you upgrade - or if you compile on a different platform.

It may also be affected by other functions as you've noticed.

You could use a generator from `<random>` instead. Every instance of such a generator will be totally unaffected by other functions that you call.

```
#include <uuid/uuid.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <random> // std::mt19937, std::uniform_int_distribution

auto& prng() {
    // Create a static seeded PRNG to use everywhere in the program
    // thread_local std::mt19937 instance(std::random_device{}());

    // A PRNG with hardcoded seed for testing:
    thread_local std::mt19937 instance(2);
    return instance;
}

int main() {
    uuid_t uuid;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 10000);

    int x = dist(prng());
    uuid_generate(uuid);
    int y = dist(prng());
    std::cout << x << '\n' << y << '\n'; // 4360 and 1851 - everywhere
}
```